# How to set hidden field to zero if radio buttons are not checked

Tags: php, radio-button

I have four radio button with name as 2d array.I want to set radio button with same name to zero if others are not checked.Please help i don't have any idea to this problem.
These radio buttons are in a while loop.

```
  A<input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value=1><?php echo $row[3]; ?>
  B<input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value=2><?php echo $row[4];?>
  C<input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]"  value=3><?php echo $row[5];?>
  D<input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]"  value=4><?php echo $row[6];?>
  <input type="hidden" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the zero input radio outside the loop (after it is quite good, in order to have assigned `$n` var) and use additional CSS to hide it:

```
//loop here    

<input type="radio" id="hiddenRadio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value="0" checked />

      <style>
          #hiddenRadio{
              visibility: hidden;
          }
      </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a radio button with the same name (outside the loop) and with the attribute 'checked', it will be marked while no others are marked. With radio buttons you only could have 1 marked input (with the same name).

`<input type='radio' name='samename' checked value='0' >
//the loop here`